# How to Implement TCP hole punching using two client sockets?

Tags: tcp, nat, handshake, hole-punching

I know about STUN, TURN and ICE. Suppose 2 users u1, u2, are behind two seperate NATs respectively. If the NAT mapping behavior is address independent and filtering behavior is port restricted NAT than How can I create a direct connection between two peers using client sockets. If any two peers who have not established connected prior to each other and if there is not mapping in NAT can two peers connect to each other if in case they know each others external ip address and port to be chose by NAT(generally same as local port)

Comment: An interesting way to connect two clients behind NAT without any 3rd party server is [ICMP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_hole_punching) (detailed paper [here](http://samy.pl/pwnat/pwnat.pdf), implementation [here](http://samy.pl/pwnat/)). PS: (AFAIK) if both sides know the external ip address and port which will be used in advance they should be able to connect easily via UDP (I just wonder how do you want to find out that information reliably)...good luck!